# Building if condition from array

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, arrays, for-loop

I have following `if` condition:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(str) &&
    (!str.ToLower().Contains("getmedia") && !str.ToLower().Contains("cmsscripts") && 
     !str.ToLower().Contains("cmspages") && !str.ToLower().Contains("asmx") &&
     !str.ToLower().Contains("cmsadmincontrols"))
  )
```

I am trying to create an array of keywords instead of putting multiple `AND` conditions, could you please help?

```
string[] excludeUrlKeyword = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ExcludeUrlKeyword"].Split(',');

for (int i = 0; i < excludeUrlKeyword.Length; i++)
{
    var sExcludeUrlKeyword = excludeUrlKeyword[i];
}
```

How to build the same if condition from the array?

Comment: Use LinQ Any or All

Comment: can we write without LINQ ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use LINQ's [`All`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548541%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) or [`Any`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972(v=vs.110).aspx) method to evaluate a condition on array elements:

```
// Check for null/empty string, then ...
var lower = str.ToLower();
if (excludeUrlKeyword.All(kw => !lower.Contains(kw))) {
    ...
}
```

Note that this is not the fastest approach: you would be better off with a regex. As an added bonus, regex would prevent "aliasing", when you discard a string with a keyword appearing as part of a longer word.

If you would like to try regex approach, change `ExcludeUrlKeyword` in the config file from comma-separated `getmedia,cmsscripts,cmspages,asmx` to pipe-separated `getmedia|cmsscripts|cmspages|asmx`, so that you could feed it directly to regex:

```
var excludeUrlRegex = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ExcludeUrlKeyword"];
if (!Regex.IsMatch(str.ToLower(), excludeUrlRegex)) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Linq `Any` should do this

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(str) && !excludeUrlKeyword.Any(x => str.ToLower().Contains(x)))
```